# How to detect if the google font is cached client side

Tags: javascript, fonts

I defer loading fonts to speed up page load

```
    var assets = {
        1:{
            type:"link",
            attributes:{
                href:"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400",
                rel:"stylesheet",
                type:"text/css"
            }
        }
    }

    for(var n=0,k=Object.keys(assets);n<k.length;n++){
        var a = document.createElement(assets[k[n]].type);
        for(var i=0,k2=Object.keys(assets[k[n]].attributes);i<k2.length;i++){
            a.setAttribute(k2[i],assets[k[n]].attributes[k2[i]]);
        }
        if(assets[k[n]].hasOwnProperty("onload")){
            assets[k[n]].onload();
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a);
    }
```

But the tendency in this process is that the page will blink to update the fonts. I am ok with the blinking but I prefer for it to happen on the initial page load only. How can I detect if the font is cached so that I can load it without deferring?

Comment: Found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231911/html-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-js-or-css-was-loaded-or-picked-up-from-the which if is the case, sucks..

Comment: You might be able to fake this type of detection, But its something i would have to write myself before i knew an answer. I'd investigate PHP file_get_contents / proxy methods or using a dynamic include / loading of the css from javascript. Perhaps using a timer function that checks how long it takes to load the css resource and compares times show how? perhaps a cookie for the longest/first time... but yea a tricky one.

Comment: set a cookie value on the first visit. after that, presumably, the cookie and cache's destiny will be intertwined; if the cookie is set, the font is cached.

Comment: `if(performance.getEntriesByType("resource").filter(function(x){return x.name.match("Open+Sans");})[0].duration) alert('cached')`

Comment: @dandavis i knew about the cookie cache trick but i find it a little unreliable if the initial load failed and the cookie was set. I guess if I set an onload listener before setting the cookie it would be more reliable. BTW, thanks for the `console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("resource"));` i like it!

Comment: That would be an option, will note it requires IE10.. But once again thats just microsoft being microsoft.. I'm currently testing a timer script .. so give me another 10 or so minutes maybe longer and will post script/results.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i got bored for a little while and was curious about this question for some reason.

Played a little and came up with the following test script.. The reason being is if i need something like this in the future i myself need to support IE8 still. **Otherwise the window.performance is the preferred option.**

The following script was a quick and dirty test script, while i would rather test this in a range of situations like a slow computer / internet connection and so on.. I am posting it as it is for anyone who may find it of use or can think of a better method for calculating the likely hood of being cached.

I was having issues with jsFiddle for some reason, so went to a local file for now.. So you can copy and paste this directly to a normal html file for testing.

**EDIT - Added Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mLuxknes/

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mayhem Tester - Font Load Time</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.14/webfontloader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Fonts Load Timer</h2>
        <input value='Indie Flower' id='txtInput' /><button id='btnLoad'>Load Font</button><br />
        <p id='txtStatus'></p>
        <script>

            var iStart = 0;
            var iFinish = 0;

            var iTestStart = 0;
            var iTestFinish = 0;

            var oStatus;
            var oFontName;

            $(function() {
                $("#btnLoad").click(btnLoadFont);
                $("#btnTest").click(btnLoadTest);
                oFontName = $("#txtInput");
                oStatus = $("#txtStatus");
            });

            function btnLoadFont() {
                oStatus.html("<b>Loading Font: </b> " + oFontName.val())
                WebFont.load({
                    google: { families: [oFontName.val()] },
                    fontloading: fntLoading,
                    fontactive: fntLoaded
                });
            }
            function fntLoading(familyName, fvd) {
                iStart = Date.now();
            }
            function fntLoaded(familyName, fvd) {
                iFinish = Date.now();
                $("h2").css({"font-family":"'" + familyName + "', serif"});
                btnLoadTest();
            }

            function btnLoadTest() {
                oStatus.html("<b>Loading Font: </b> " + oFontName.val())
                WebFont.load({
                    google: { families: [oFontName.val()] },
                    fontloading: fntLoadingTest,
                    fontactive: fntLoadedTest
                });
            }
            function fntLoadingTest(familyName, fvd) {
                iTestStart = Date.now();
            }
            function fntLoadedTest(familyName, fvd) {
                iTestFinish = Date.now();
                $("h2").css({"font-family":"'" + familyName + "', serif"});
                var iFirst = iFinish - iStart;
                var iTest = iTestFinish - iTestStart;
                var iFP = (100 - iFirst) / 100 * 100;
                var iTP = (100 - iTest) / 100 * 100;
                var sFirst = "Loaded from cache";
                var sLast = "Loaded from cache";
                if (iFP < 50) { sFirst = "Not loaded from Cache"  }
                if (iTP < 50) { sLast = "Not loaded from Cache"   }
                oStatus.html(
                    "<b>Font Test: </b> " + familyName + "<br />" +
                    "<b>First Load: </b>" + iFirst + " milliseconds  / " + sFirst + " <br />" +
                    "<b>Second Load: </b>" + iTest + " milliseconds  / " + sLast + " <br />"
                )
            }
            // FIX IE As Usual
            if (!Date.now) {
                Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
            }           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What does the script do?**

It simple uses the Web Font Loader lib to use the callback methods for when a font has been loaded and rendered.

We simple get a timestamp before we load the font and get a timestamp after it has been loaded/rendered and work with the difference..

**Accuracy - Only use as a back up**

In general when testing i would get around **230ms** to **1200ms** for fonts load and render times otherwise always **< 3ms** for cached fonts.

So while this is not accurate, maybe someone can think of a better method of comparing the two load times and checking the averages between them or something.

Comment: And no comments about cleaning up the JS code please, i know its messy.. But yea on to the next project for now ;)